# Paramiko passwordless SSH NameError Raspberry Pi2

Tags: bash, ssh, rsa, raspberry-pi2, paramiko

I am working on Raspberry Pi2 to setup sensor and alarm for automation. Currently trying to get ssh file transfer functionalities with my Mac. I was able to get passwordless setup via bash terminal using ssh-keygen and sharing rsa public file to mac. But, I am unable to do it using Python, currently using paramiko.

Here's my code and the error produced:-

```
IP="xxx.xxx.x.xxx"
username="xyz"
import paramiko
import os
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
privatekeyfile=os.path.expanduser('/address/on_pi/to/id_rsa')
mykey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile)
ssh.connect(IP[0],username=user[0], pkey=mykey)
x_file=open('/address/on/remote/mac/file.txt','w')
x_file.write("anything")
```

The error comes as:-

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
  File "my_paramiko.py", line 8, in <module>
    ssh.connect(IP[0],username=user[0], pkey=mykey)
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

My python version is 2.7.3 and paramiko is 1.7.7.1 (George)

I researched for solution, but most of them did only with bash terminal, or had errors in reading keys.

*EDIT*

The problem was solved. Instead of using

```
ssh.connect(IP[0],username=user[0], pkey=mykey)
```

I used

```
ssh.connect("xxx.xxx.x.xxx", username="xyz", pkey=mykey)
stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("ls -l")
```

Then called in sftp

```
sftp=ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put('file/address','file/address')
sftp.close
ssh.close
```

Even though it worked, I am in some doubt about the code. Please suggest or point out if any redundant method identified, or if there a better way.

Thanks

Comment: ``ssh.connect(IP[0],username=user[0], pkey=mykey)`` the user[0] is not defined it seems.

Comment: Try `ssh.connect(IP[0],username=username, pkey=mykey)` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Dilettant. Please review the changes made and suggest if any better possible.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @terminal. Please review the changes. :)

Comment: Why not `ssh.connect(IP,username=username, pkey=mykey)`? `IP` is a string carrying an IP address in your code, username also is a string that carries the "xyz" as value.

Comment: @Dilettant
Ofcourse! It was redundant to type in IP again in ssh.connect, You were right. I ran again using IP and username variables. It worked. Thanks :)